# How to make button in tree view always visible odoo 15

Tags: button, visible, odoo-15

In odoo 15, i've created a button in tree view, but it not always visible, i must click on a record in the tree view to make the button appear.

[image]
[image]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="grabfood_orders_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">grabfood.orders.tree</field>
            <field name="model">grabfood.orders</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree create="false">
                    <header>
                        <button string="Read GrabFood API" name="action_read_grabfood_api" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                    </header>
                    <field name="name"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What is the use case for this requirement I am curious

Comment: I just wanna create a button to run an action, but with above code, the button is always invisible unless i click on the records. The action i wanna do is to run an API and return the result.

Comment: There might be an easy way in odoo 15 but with my knowledge, I would ask you refer mrp_mps module button "Add a product" https://demo3.odoo.com/web#cids=1&action=1186&menu_id=866 you will need to use JS snippet which could be tricky and from js call your function that is calling the api
It's enterprise code

Comment: thanks @MuhammadYusuf, i will try your solution and report to you as soon as posible.

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf, i don't see "add a product" button in Manufacture module

Comment: Oh, i've found it, it's inside odoo-enterprise version.

Comment: @fudu did you solve this?

Comment: @Dominik not yet, this is hard to do, and with alot of custom js, which i'm not able to handle because i'm still new for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
https://github.com/Tlki/web_tree_header_buttons_always_visible

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <odoo>
        <data>
            <record id="grabfood_orders_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">grabfood.orders.tree</field>
                <field name="model">grabfood.orders</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <tree create="false">
                        <header>
                            <button string="Read GrabFood API" 
         name="action_read_grabfood_api" type="object" class="btn-primary"
    attrs="{'always_visible': True}"
    />
                        </header>
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </record>
        </data>
    </odoo>
```

Comment: Not working in Odoo14, is there any way to do it on Odoo14?

Comment: Hi @H.Selam, this does not work in Odoo14, is t here any way to do this in Odoo14?